# getting boolean or string from ASP.NET Web API via IOS

Tags: ios, asp.net, json, nsjsonserialization

I can get the value in JSON format with the function:

```
NSMutableArray *jsonArrayClass = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];
```

But i really have no idea how to get the string value or boolean value. we have some validation will return this data type. not JSON.

The raw value shown on Flidder looks like (ID00001 is the return string):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 07 Apr 2014 17:15:28 GMT
Content-Length: 9

"ID00001"
```

Comment: ID00001 is not valid JSON, That is the API's fault

Comment: yes i know it is not JSON, as i only know how to get JSON from webapi, I want to get this value to my IOS app.

Comment: What is in the `data` you received ?

Comment: ID00001 is the data i received, it is a string. how to get it from Xcode ? pls kindly assist

Comment: `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` try this

Comment: it works , thx a lot Faisal Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Yes this is the answer like Faisal Ali provided. how can i mark u 2 guys as answer ? it said i need 15 reputaion to mark answer....